# System.Exception : Failed to execute: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.202.101:5555 install -g

Tags: xamarin, uitest

I am getting below issue while executing test with Virtual Device.

My Story is like... I am a new in Xamarin UITest and while beginning it was working fine but once I get latest .apk from our Dev. Team and it started to throw errors for virtual devices only, although it is working fine with Real Devices. but not working with Genymotion simulators. Please help...

Test Name: AppLaunches
Test FullName: ZeroChaosUITest.Tests(Android).AppLaunches
Test Source: C:\SAJID SIDI\Xamarin\Projects\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\Tests\Tests.cs : line 30
Test Outcome: Failed
Test Duration: 0:00:01.996

Result StackTrace:
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Processes.ProcessRunner.Run(String path, String arguments, IEnumerable1 noExceptionOnExitCodes) at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.Adb.AdbProcessRunner.Run(String adbArguments, Int32[] noExceptionsOnExitCodes) at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.Commands.CommandAdbInstallPackage.c__AnonStorey0.<>m__0(String args) at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.Commands.CommandAdbInstallPackage.ExecuteInner(Func2 adbShell, Int32 deviceSdkVersion)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.Commands.CommandAdbInstallPackage.Execute(AdbProcessRunner processRunner, IExecutor executor)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Execution.Executor.Execute[TDep1,TDep2](ICommand`2 command)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.InstallApps(ApkFile[] apkFiles)
at Xamarin.UITest.Shared.Android.LocalAndroidAppLifeCycle.EnsureInstalled(ApkFile appApkFile, ApkFile testServerApkFile)
at Xamarin.UITest.Android.AndroidApp..ctor(IAndroidAppConfiguration appConfiguration, IExecutor executor)
at Xamarin.UITest.Configuration.AndroidAppConfigurator.StartApp(AppDataMode appDataMode)
at ZeroChaosUITest.AppInitializer.StartApp(Platform platform) in C:\SAJID SIDI\Xamarin\Projects\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\AppInitializer.cs:line 26
at ZeroChaosUITest.Tests.BeforeEachTest() in C:\SAJID SIDI\Xamarin\Projects\ZeroChaosUITest-master\ZeroChaosUITest\Tests\Tests.cs:line 25
Result Message: 
SetUp : System.Exception : Failed to execute: C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe -s 192.168.202.101:5555 install -g "C:\Users\ssidi\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-77710D38FAFC1E54041539C1991A3D35B8C9FC4E\final-A7778C8A1BD5066ABCC133FD188BF7ECA8F9AE65.apk" - exit code: 1
Failed to install C:\Users\ssidi\AppData\Local\Temp\uitest\a-77710D38FAFC1E54041539C1991A3D35B8C9FC4E\final-A7778C8A1BD5066ABCC133FD188BF7ECA8F9AE65.apk: Failure [INSTALL_FAILED_NO_MATCHING_ABIS: Failed to extract native libraries, res=-113]

Comment: Are you able to install & launch the APK on the virtual device manually, without running Xamarin.UITest? What Android version & device model are you attempting to deploy on?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution that I've found here: 
https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/105753/error-deploying-to-simulator-in-release-mode
[image]

Source: